# What is the design best practice for setting the page width for mobile web pages?

Tags: css, mobile, width, mobile-website, screen-resolution

Different browsers on different phones have different screen resolution.

Is there a best practice in the community to set the width to a standard size, so that it works on most moderns phones and browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO the best practise is to get along without too many assumptions about width and resolution of the clients device.

Mostly those devices have browsers geared towards displaying/flowing/reducing webpages. If at all possible, let the browser do the work.

Answer (score 7):

There's no easy way to ensure pixel-perfect accuracy across mobile browsers (actually, there's no easy way to do that with **any** browser). There are, however, some methods to help with that kind of work. For example, mobile Safari for the iPhone supports a 'viewport' meta tag that allows you to specify attributes like width. Here are some examples of usage:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width = 750px" />`

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=2.5, user-scalable=no" />`

Apple has some information [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html), and you'll find a lot more information across the web.

Answer (score 1):

G'day,

I know you're question is to decide on making a selection of the optimum screen size to work on all phones but that approach soon wears thin with users.

A large web site I'm associated with takes the UserAgent string and normalises it to a common denominator, e.g. over 300 different UA strings in use in the UK for a particular Sony Ericsson phone type so they all get converted to the same string, and then does a lookup into a table to determine screen real estate.

The coders also have access to the current connection speed which is deduced by a geolocation application based on connection type, routing type, etc. **at the time of the request.** You don't want to be sending rich, high-def media to someone with a slow connection.

This is then used to

1. decide if rich content can be served, and then
2. select the optimum format for the content.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You could always use "ems" instead of pixels they *should* scale properly.

This is still a touchy subject since many mobile browsers basically interpret what you have depending on how the devs wanted to make it interpret.